# How to pick and resampling time series data like start and stop and value from python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm doing data analysis for time series data.
And I need to re-sample time series data like this way below.
Please Give me some advice.
I try to use iloc thing but no idea.

There is data like this.

```py
               DateTime  value
0   2019-09-10 11:00:00    NaN
1   2019-09-10 11:00:01    NaN
2   2019-09-10 11:00:02    5.0
3   2019-09-10 11:00:03    1.0
4   2019-09-10 11:00:04    6.0
5   2019-09-10 11:00:05    3.0
6   2019-09-10 11:00:06    8.0
7   2019-09-10 11:00:07    1.0
8   2019-09-10 11:00:08    NaN
9   2019-09-10 11:00:09    NaN
10  2019-09-10 11:00:10    NaN
11  2019-09-10 11:00:11    NaN
12  2019-09-10 11:00:12    NaN
13  2019-09-10 11:00:13    NaN
14  2019-09-10 11:00:14    7.0
15  2019-09-10 11:00:15    2.0
16  2019-09-10 11:00:16   53.0
17  2019-09-10 11:00:17    1.0
18  2019-09-10 11:00:18    8.0
19  2019-09-10 11:00:19   71.0
20  2019-09-10 11:00:20    NaN
21  2019-09-10 11:00:21    NaN
22  2019-09-10 11:00:22    NaN
23  2019-09-10 11:00:23    NaN
```

Result I expected below.

```py
                ID                Start                 Stop  Max  Min
0  2019-09-10_0001  2019-09-10 11:00:02  2019-09-10 11:00:07    8    1
1  2019-09-10_0001  2019-09-10 11:00:02  2019-09-10 11:00:07    8    1
```

Comment: `NaN` is the correct output as the `dtype` is numeric.

Comment: Yes. I mean there is null in my database. Thank you for your reply.